# Loop in structured data in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json-ld

I am trying to use structured data in rails, but it is not working properly. Below is my code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
<%=
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": @faq[:lists].each do |item|
    item[:list].map do |list|
      {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": list[:heading],
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": list[:desc]
        }
      }
    end
  end
}.to_json.html_safe
%>
</script>
```

What I am doing?

Comment: `@faq[:lists].each` => `@faq[:lists].map` ?

Comment: @romainsalles But there would be array which is inside a array. I mean multidimenstional array

Comment: Give this gem a try: https://github.com/RocketApex/page_structured_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `mainEntity` to be a simple array (not an array of arrays), you can try this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
<%=
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": @faq[:lists].map do |item|
    item[:list].map do |list|
      {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": list[:heading],
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": list[:desc]
        }
      }
    end
  end.flatten # <===== array[array] --> array
}.to_json.html_safe
%>
</script>
```

See: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten

Comment: Not with the "flatten" part. Or maybe I don't understand what you want at the end?
Could you give me an example of the expected result?